# Neptune, Python, Gremlin: Update a property in a graph vertex with an array of values

Tags: python, gremlin, traversal, amazon-neptune

Using Amazon Neptune as a GraphDB, I'm trying to update a property of some of the vertex to include a list of values. The basic gremlin example from this [guide](https://kelvinlawrence.net/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.html):

```
// Add a list as a property value
g.V().has('code','AUS').property('places',out().values('code').fold())
```

Is failing with:

```
{
  "requestId": "XXX",
  "detailedMessage": "Unsupported property value type: java.util.ArrayList",
  "code": "UnsupportedOperationException"
}
```

I tried also to add the `list` modifier

```
g.V().has('code','AUS').property(list, 'places',out().values('code').fold())
```

is failing with:

```
{
  "requestId": "XXX",
  "detailedMessage": "list cardinality for vertex property is not supported",
  "code": "UnsupportedOperationException"
}
```

If for some reason the python-gremlin or Amazon Neptune flavors don't support array or list as a property value, I can settle for a single value that will concatenate the values into a single string. I tried using various options:

```
g.V().has('code','AUS').property('places',out().values('code').fold(0) {a,b -> a + b.length()})
```

or

```
g.V().has('code','AUS').property('places',out().values('code')map {join(",",it.get().value('code'))})
```

but none is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to insert each value in a separate `property` step

like this:

```
g.V().has('code', 'AUS').as('airport').
  out().values('code').as('code').select('airport').
  property(set, 'places', select('code'))
```

***EDIT:***

I see in the AWS [user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/engine-releases-1.0.1.0.200264.0.html) that list cardinality is not supported. therefore the closest solution is to use the `set` cardinality.

> Neptune supports set cardinality and single cardinality. If it isn't specified, set cardinality is selected. This means that if you set a property value, it adds a new value to the property, but only if it doesn't already appear in the set of values. This is the Gremlin enumeration value of Set. **List is not supported**. For more information about property cardinality, see the Vertex topic in the Gremlin JavaDoc.

example: https://gremlify.com/9v

Comment: Thanks for the cleaner query, however, I'm still getting the error: "list cardinality for vertex property is not supported". It might be a limitation of the Amazon Neptune implementation.

Comment: @Guy you are right.. Neptune doesn't support list cardinality

Comment: Thanks, @noam621. `set` did the trick and also removed the need to run dedup on the values.